# BroadcastReceiver repeats without change

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I call a BroadcastReceiver from an Activity

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmRec.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("lol",0);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, pendingIntent);
```

Its onReceivemethod is this:

```
        int lol=intent.getExtras().getInt("lol");
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running "+lol, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    lol++;
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmRec.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("lol",lol);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, pendingIntent);
```

Basially, every time the Receiver is called, it should show a Toast  It's Running plus an incremented value(1,2,3 etc). However, it always shows It's Running 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `lol` isn't getting incremented!

Your concept is totally wrong ~

`int lol` and `String lol` are different objects. You have to pass the same object in both areas like below.

**Class 1 : (Activity)**

```
....
AlarmManager manager =...
....
manager.setRepeating(.....); //use to repeat + don't need to pass lol
```

**Class 2 : (Receiver)**

```
.... 
public static int LOL = 0;
....
onReceive(....){
LOL++;
Toast.makeText(....,(String)LOL,....).show();
}
```

**Otherwise**

Increment `lol` in Class 1, then send the value to `Class 2`. Just implement toast in Class 2.

*Like :*

```
int lol =0
for(;;) {   //a forever loop which runs until your device die
sendToClass2(lol++);
}

private void sendToClass2(int foe){
....
alarmIntent.putExtra("lol",foe);
....
manager.setExact(...); // If you really love to use seExact use this
}
```

Besides that, why you're trying to launch 2nd class from the code exists in itself? Isn't a bad and complex idea, even not working as your question suggest.

Comment: First solution will not work, broadcast receivers are destroyed after onReceive, next call will also start from 0. I am not sure what you are doing in the second solution, but I think it will create the same problem. I use setExact to make sure that the code happens frequently and on time, I don't know when setRepeating will execute. Basically, I am interested in comparing a location from gps with the previous one, this code is a test to see how to save values between calls. I know I should use locationManger/fusedlocationAPI but the results are problematic

Comment: You want to save values between calls? Then why a variable? Please use `SharedPreference` & your concept is wrong: **Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid** (from the docs) so, a BroadcastReceiver isn't destroyed after a `onReceived` call :

Further on it check my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628103/8572503

Comment: Your procedure is too much complex , your work can be done in an easy manner

Comment: so, if I manually register a receiver, its variables will remain. Thanks for that

Comment: @Orcha , you're welcome. Feel free to ask for further help.