# Android One plus 6(Android pie version) BOOT COMPLETE Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android

Android One plus 6(Android pie  version) BOOT COMPLETE Broadcast Receiver not working

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".service.ConnectionReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

below is my reciever class :

```
public class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.d("API123", "" + intent.getAction());
  Toast.makeText(context, "isatRunningonbootanyproblem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  context.startService(newIntent(context, MyBackgroundService.class));
 }
}
```

I need to start my service once boot get completed. Please suggest what should i do

below is error log i am getting

```
 018-11-06 05:25:34.994 885-3000/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=oneplus.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE flg=0x10 } to test.myapplication/.MyReceiver
    2018-11-06 05:25:38.241 885-3000/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to test.myapplication/.MyReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE due to sender android (uid 1000)
```

Comment: Did you add the `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission to your `Manifest`?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 is added

Comment: updated the error log in question please have a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced same problem in OnePlus 6. I was going to make background service and it should be auto-started after restarting device.
The BOOT_COMPLETED intent received for most devices, but not working in OnePlus 6.
I tried to search and found solution. The reason is that my app is optimized on Battery Optimization.
I changed the status to *Not Optimized*, after that it's working well.

Add permission on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

White-list / optimization enabled your app

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
        }
    }
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: you can not use this permission in your app, play store will not allow this

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

This permission's level is normal. There is no any restriction to use it. Why will play store will not allow this?

Comment: Great solution!. Although, accepting the `IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` popup does not change the setting in my Onplus 6t running on android P.  I started `Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS` intent and manually set it to `Don't optimize`.

Comment: strange but seems not working in my xiomi device

Answer (score 1):

This is a special broadcast which you must hold a specific permission in order to receive (from the documentation for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`):

> You must hold the Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in order to receive this broadcast.

Be sure to declare that in your manifest.  No runtime permissions are needed since it is a "normal" level permission.  However, your app must also get started for the first time by the user (e.g. an `Activity` in your app) before the system will ever deliver this broadcast to your app.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 is added still not working

Comment: Did you start your app via an `Activity` after it has been installed?

Comment: Yes I did run the app . Then close the app , kill it from background and then restarted the device

Comment: updated the error log in question please have a look

Comment: From that error it looks as though your `BroadcastReceiver` was triggered but the `Service` is not allowed to start due to background limitations imposed starting with Oreo.  You need to make the `Service` a foreground service, or use `JobScheduler` (really, look at `WorkManager` as the new, most compatible way to do this.)

Comment: can you please help me a little more i have posted code here please have look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170250/android-service-not-getting-start-from-jobintentservice-on-boot/53170438#53170438

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a Service from a Receiver that gets pinged in the background on API 26+. This is not specific to the One Plus 6 -- it's universal across all phones.

See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

You can get around this restriction with an ugly workaround:

From your Receiver, start an Activity instead of the Service (declare the Activity in your Manifest as well):

```
<activity android:name=".DummyActivity" />
```

...

```
public class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, DummyActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(startActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

In the DummyActivity, immediately start your Service, then call finish()

```
public class DummyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MyBackgroundService.class);
        startService(startServiceIntent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

The screen will flicker momentarily as the Activity starts then finishes immediately, but the experience isn't too jarring for users.

Consider the nature of your background work and strongly consider moving to more modern APIs, such as [Work Manager.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) Again, the behavior above is ugly and ongoing background Services are being pushed out by battery life improvement efforts by Google. If you insist on using a Service, and the work being done is ongoing, you should be using a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).

Across a few hardware/sensor stacks, new APIs have been added for API 26+ to help you avoid manual ongoing background work in Services. For example, BluetoothLeScanner added [an overload to startScan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) that takes a [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) as a parameter instead of a [ScanCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback), so that you can let the system perform your predefined operation in the future, instead of having to keep a scope open (in a Service) in order to handle ScanCallback function calls.

Comment: Is it possible to schedule a job. and execution of that job will start the service ??

Comment: its not working app is not starting. getting same error log as mentioned in question

Comment: No you cannot-- there are security considerations to consider as well. Google, in general, doesn't want apps doing long operations in the background without notifying the user. Therefore, you cannot start background Services from scopes that are already in the background. Hence, the ugly workaround above that starts a Service in the foreground from an Activity that the user will never interact with or even see.

Comment: See my most recent edit: I changed startService (in the Receiver) to startActivity. Sorry about that!

Comment: 2018-11-06 06:29:40.498 879-1984/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to studenttrainerapp.istar.studenttrainer.myapplication/.MyReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE due to sender android (uid 1000)
getting this error now

Comment: it seem boot complete is not able to work here. i am getting this  Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=oneplus.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE flg=0x10 } to studenttrainerapp.istar.studenttrainer.myapplication/.MyReceiver